# Interactive "screen" for WCF hosted in service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, debugging, service

I have a WCF Service that I already mention in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578050/heap-memory-problems). As I have read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx) host WCF in Windows service is the best solution for all reasons. So that's why I select this option. But windows service hosting doesn't allow any visual process communication (before we used self-hosted service, that have hosted in console application and report any problems just into console). How can I get similar way for hosting service? My thoughts is about using another named pipes binding for visual "communication" between service and human. 
I would be very nice for me if somebody recommend me something useful.
Thanks very much in advance guys!

Answer (score 3):

In case you need the "Screen" just so that the service can report the problems, the I would suggest that you use windows event to log such events from the service and then you can create any UI/back ground process that can look for such events in window event log and report them appropriately (ex: sending email etc)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please point me some articles, samples about "windows event"?

Comment: @kseen: Google is your friend - also MSDN docs! See [How to write to an event log in C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307024) and the [MSDN docs for the EventLog class in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx)

Comment: Check out - `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx` for event log class. And `http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/LogWatcherRSSFeeds.aspx` for an example how you can monitor event logs.

Comment: @marc_s MSDN Docs is the best friend you can have!

Answer (score 1):

I tend to agree with @Ankur's answer, but figured I'd give you an alternative option. You could consider using WMI provide visual feedback to a running service. I attended an interesting ALT.NET talk on the subject (not WCF specific) a while back ([full video is available here](http://www.viddler.com/explore/sergiopereira/videos/23/)) and it should be relatively straightforward to instrument your application with WMI to allow you system state to be queried

Comment: I guess using WMI would only be able to query the "current state" and not previous states right?